# To find order of permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $\sigma$ be the permutation given by [image]

Is their a short way to do this.Thanks

Comment: Write $\sigma$ as a [product of disjoint cycles](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319979/how-to-write-permutations-as-product-of-disjoint-cycles-and-transpositions).

Comment: I guess this was downvoted because it's a pasted image with multiple choice answers. I don't see a problem with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. The order of the permutation is the least common multiple of the order of each cycle.

Comment: So answer is 12

Comment: Yes ma'm that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

We have a cycle of length 4, a cycle of length 3, and a cycle of length 2. Raising to a power that is a multiple of 4 makes the length 4 cycle go away, as well as the length 2. Raising to a multiple of 3 makes the 3-cycle go away. But we want them *all* to go away. What can we do?

Comment: "Raising to a power that is a multiple of 4 makes the length 4 cycle go away"..Why is that so?

Comment: @Sophie try explicitly raising a 4 cycle to the fourth power and you'll see. In general an $n$-cycle has order $n$. The reason the method in the other answer works is because the disjoint cycles commute, so raising the permutation to a power is the same as raising all of the cycles to the same power.