# Decomposing a permutation into multiplication of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I have a permutation in cyclic notation, for example $(132)$, and i want to represent it as multiplication of transpositions.

What is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: See also [this duplicate which shows two tried-and-true methods](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/320011/9003)

Comment: In your example $(132)$, the first method defined would yield: $(12)(13)$, and the second method would yield, as in the answer below, $(13)(32)$.  Both products yield $(132)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it matters what $(132)$ means (i.e. whether it means $1\to3\to2\to1$ or $2\to3\to1\to2$). If it means the former (which is the convention I use),
then $(132)=(13)(32)=(13)(23)$. In general, you can write $$(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=(a_1a_2)(a_2a_3)\cdots(a_{n-1}a_n).$$