# Permutation written as a single cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

How do I rewrite $(1\,2)(1\,3)(1\,4)(1\,5)$ as a single cycle?  I have tried questions in the form: $(1\,4\,3\,5\,2)(4\,5\,3\,2\,1)$.

Comment: You can just individually check where each element $x \in \{1,2,3,4,5 \}$ maps and construct a single cycle

Comment: What are the steps to show that the answer is (12345)? Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that as a composition of functions, $(1\,2)(1\,3)(1\,4)(1\,5)$ is to be read from right to left.

Now what happens to $1$? It's mapped to $5$ by the first transposition, and then all other transpositions fix $5$.  So overall $$1\longrightarrow 5$$

What happens to $5$ now? The first transposition maps $5$ to $1$, then the second maps $1$ to $4$, and $4$ is fixed by the remaining transpositions. So we get:
$$1\longrightarrow 5\longrightarrow 4$$
Similarly you get $ 4\longrightarrow 3$ and $3\longrightarrow 2$, so that  in the end $$1\longrightarrow 5\longrightarrow 4\longrightarrow 3\longrightarrow 2$$
Which is usually written as $(1\,5\,4\,3\,2)$.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudMortier for taking the time to explain the steps. Most helpful!!

Comment: @gradstudent3746 You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For a product of transpositions, just reverse the order! $$(1\,2)(1\,3)(1\,4)(1\,5)=(1\,5\,4\,3\,2)$$

Comment: (15432) was my first answer on my first attempt, but I was informed the answer was (12345). Is this somehow a different form of the same answer? How would I show that it is (12345)?

Comment: No, $(1\,5\,4\,3\,2)$ is not the same as $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$.

Comment: I didnt think so, but I have now received two different responses that the answer is (12345) and someone else says (15432).

Comment: Note that $$(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)=(1\,5)(1\,4)(1\,3)(1\,2)$$ which is something different.

Comment: If it helps, please see the comments in the answer to [this post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319979/how-to-write-permutations-as-product-of-disjoint-cycles-and-transpositions).

Comment: @gradstudent3746 The two answers you have gotten correspond to the two conventions for multiplying cycles. Some texts/people assume left to right, some right to left. Annoying, but that's how it is.