# Permutation as a Product of $2$ cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\2&3&4&5&1&7&8&6\end{bmatrix}

I have already written this permutation as disjoint cycles: (12345)(678)

My attempt at a product of two cycles: (12)(23)(34)(45)(67)(78), but I don't really think this is right, and if it is right, I'm not sure why. It's just an honest guess.

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me.

Comment: Why don't you just work out the product of those six $2$-cycles and see what you get? Hint: it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, your product of disjoint cycles correctly represent the given permutation.  And also your transpositions from the disjoint cycles are spot on.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/320011/9003) for a more thorough discussion of ways to write the product of transpositions for disjoint permutations.

Comment: I've already seen that answer, but as I can't comment yet due to not having enough reputation, I figured it might be better to ask my own question. In that answer, I have no idea how they were able to get their answer in method 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. In general we have $(x_1, x_2, x_3,...,x_k)=(x_1, x_2)(x_2, x_3)(x_3, x_4)...(x_{k-1}, x_k)$. Very easy to see why this is correct, just check where does each of the two permutations send each element.