# Writing a set permutation as a product of transpositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let $\begin{equation*}
p = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
1 & 8 & 4 & 7 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$

I would like to write $p$ as a product of transpositions. To do this, I first write out $p$ as a product of disjoint cycles as follows:

$p = (6)\circ(2, 8, 5, 3, 4, 7)\circ(1)$

or, in simpler terms, given the fact that we can drop all single element brackets:

$p = (2, 8, 5, 3, 4, 7)$

I know this is correct because when I calculate the above permutation, I end up with the given $p$.

My challenge now comes in when I expand on this intermediary step and write out the product of transpositions, i.e. splitting these cycles to length 2. According to *@amWhy's* answer on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319979/how-to-write-permutations-as-product-of-disjoint-cycles-and-transpositions) thread, I use the quoted method with an example given:
$Method 1: τ=(1,3,4,6,7,9)=(1,9)(1,7)(1,6)(1,4)(1,3)$

Using this method on my example gives this answer:
$p = (2,7)\circ(2,4)\circ(2,3)\circ(2,5)\circ(2,8)$

However checking this answer by multiplying out this product doesnt give me the original $p$ in the question.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You must be multiplying out the transpositions wrongly - maybe you are reading them in the wrong order. What do you get when you multiply them?

Comment: Multiplying out my product of transpositions gives $\begin{equation*}
p = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
1 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$ I always work from right to left when multiplying the product

Comment: Hey Matthew, you're right. I wasn't multiplying correctly. On a high level I followed right to left but each operand was still multiplied incorrectly. What I accidentally did was this: $A\circ B \circ C \circ D \circ E$ as a first step I started going right to left  and calculated $D \circ E$ but I swapped my order of evaluating that product. In other words in every step from going right to left I evaluated each product incorrectly. Thanks, good spot